# Changing text color of dialog builder buttons

Tags: android, styles, android-alertdialog

I am attempting to change the color of the buttons that appear when I use the dialog builder.

> new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.AppTheme)...

I have my style resources as follows below. The message background color and text are changed but the buttons still show as white with black text. I know I could theoretically create a new layout for the dialog but that seems like overkill just for changing the text color.

Any input is appreciated.

> ```
> <resources>
>
>     <!-- Base application theme. -->
>
>
>     <style name="AppTheme" parent="">
>         <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
>         <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
>         <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
>         <item name="android:button">@style/Button</item>
>
>     </style>
>     <style name="Button" parent="">
>         <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
>         <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
>
>     </style>
>
> </resources>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Activity and display it as a dialog.

Simply create an activity and set its theme to Theme.Holo.Dialog in the manifest:

```
activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"
```

This activity is displayed as a dialog window instead of fullscreen.

Like that, you can define your global layout as you usually do for any other activity and you can define the custom buttons for your dialog.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. However as mentioned in my post I rather not have to create a new xml file and especially a new activity if I can change the text color without doing so.